# Should we point regionalisms in answers ?

Tags: discussion, answers

I have started browsing French.SE recently and as a French Canadian noticed that quite a few users write in France french. The matter of questions about regionalisms has been brought up on meta but what about when the question is from someone learning French and the answer(s) point to France's french ?

It personally irritates me to see those answers being upvoted without any mention that this is not generic french that will be understood everywhere.

See this question:
[How to ask "how often" in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11409/how-to-ask-how-often-in-french)

The accepted answer would probably cause an awkward situation in Quebec, for example, as one would think the sentence is not complete or does not make sense.

Another example here where the accepted answer presents swears used in France but not in all dialects of french (my reference being Quebec).

[Learning common French insults/pejoratives?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4577/learning-common-french-insults-pejoratives)

How should we deal with those cases ? I feel the unknowing learner risks not being understood because he is using regionalisms and should at least understand when he is using them. I thought about commenting but it would be tedious as there are lots of those answers. Downvoting seems a bit much since the answer is not necessarily bad per se. Flagging seems useless.

Comment: I totally agree that it's always useful to precise this kind of things, like *where*, *when* or *with who* some expression can be used. But isn't it a bit far fetched to describe France's french as a regionalism ? Would it really be insulting to other versions to consider it some kind of ... default/standard french ?

Comment: @romainvaleri No. There are many countries where French is spoken. We are a few millions in Canada speaking French and I know it is also spoken in many African countries. Using expressions from France and not flagging them as regionalisms is akin to saying that France's French is more valid than what is used in other countries.

Comment: More valid ? I guess I can't make sense of that. I don't think France's french is in any way *better* or *more valid*. I just pointed out that, without specific information when an expression is mentionned, one can probably assume that it's *vanilla french* if I can say. With, of course, variants out of France and **also** variants in some regions inside France itself. But please don't misunderstand me : this is **not** about purity of language (whatever it could mean) or about different dialects' merits and beauties.

Answer (score 10):

Je crois que le format de stackexchange permet très bien de faire face à ce genre de situation.

Il faut reconnaître qu'il est difficile à un francophone de France de connaître toutes les variantes de français. En France même, les Français sont peu exposés au différentes variantes du français, qu'il soit québécois, belge, suisse, etc.
Les francophones d'autres régions de la francophonie sont certainement plus sensibles aux différences entre le français qu'ils pratiquent et celui parlé en France ; par contre ils ne connaissent certainement pas toutes les variantes de français. 
Certaines personnes qui répondent signalent parfois que leur réponse se base sur ce qui est dit dans leur partie du monde mais il me semble que ce sont plutôt les francophones non français qui pensent à le dire.

Ce constat fait comment se comporter ?
Je suis d'accord qu'on ne peut pas moinsoyer la réponse. Encore moins la signaler, non pas parce que ce serait inutile (les modérateurs réagissent toujours très vite) mais par ce que ce serait inapproprié dans ce cas qui ne nécessite pas l'intervention d'un modérateur.

Par contre il ne faut pas oublier qu'aucune réponse apportée sur un site de Stackexchange n'est définitive. 
Il est vrai que certaines personnes qui posent une question s’empressent parfois d'accepter un peu trop vite une réponse, probablement par souci de vouloir montrer leur gratitude envers celui qui a répondu. Mais le fait qu'une réponse ait été acceptée n'empêche pas  :

- Celui qui a eu sa réponse acceptée, de la modifier, par exemple suite à un commentaire nouveau qui a été mis sous sa réponse.
- Quelqu'un d'autre d'apporter une nouvelle réponse.
- Celui qui a posé la question de modifier son choix pour la réponse acceptée.

Cette dernière option, non pas parce que je pense que tout le monde ne vient ici que pour la course aux points, mais parce que je pense que le fait qu'une bonne réponse soit marquée comme acceptée est - ou peut être - perçu comme un signe de validation par la communauté. C'est l'image que le site reflète à quelqu'un qui y arrive qui est en cause.
Or il m'est plusieurs fois arrivé de remarquer, et pas seulement sur French Language, que la réponse acceptée est loin d'être la meilleure, et que parfois elle n'est même pas bonne du tout. Loin de moi la volonté de blâmer celui qui a accepté la bonne réponse, s'il a posé la question, par définition c'est qu'il n'en connaissait pas la réponse, et son acceptation se fait en toute bonne foi. C'est la communauté du site que je remets en question, faisons-nous assez pour intervenir, pour surveiller, pour remettre en question ? Plusoyons-nous régulièrement les réponses qui le méritent quand on estime que la réponse donnée est bonne ? Car dans certains cas le nombre de votes face aux réponses peut servir d'indicateur à celui qui pose la question pour faire son choix.

Par ailleurs la structure même de Stackexchange donne à tous, graduellement mais assez rapidement, des outils d'interventions (corrections, commentaires pour des remarques et précisions, etc.) et de modérations (signalements, demandes de fermeture, etc.) et ne pouvons-nous pas les utiliser mieux ou plus ?
Le fait de modifier une réponse déjà sur le site, même faite il y a longtemps, ou de fournir une nouvelle réponse, remet la question automatiquement en tête de la pile *active* ce qui lui donne une seconde vie et du coup elle devient visible par de nouveaux venus qui n'auraient pas eu l'occasion de la voir autrement.

Pour en revenir à l'essence même de la question :

> I feel the unknowing learner risks not being understood because he is using regionalisms and should at least understand when he is using them.

I couldn't agree more. And in my opinion I think it is your role as a French Canadian to stand up on questions concerning Québécois French, not only because someone has asked a question and might like to know the answer but because you should feel it as a duty to the Francophonie to say that France French is not the only kind of French written and spoken on planet Earth.

En ce qui concerne les exemples que tu donnes :
[How to ask "how often" in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11409/how-to-ask-how-often-in-french)
Je vois que tu as laissé un commentaire, mais tu pourrais très bien faire une réponse, en précisant ce qui serait acceptable/compris **au Québec**.

[Learning common French insults/pejoratives?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4577/learning-common-french-insults-pejoratives)
Là aussi tu pourrais faire une réponse spécifique, en indiquant à partir des réponses déjà données les différences d'acceptabilité entre la France et le Québec et en complétant par ce qui est typiquement québécois et ignoré dans les réponses précédentes. (On a déjà eu une question sur [les sacres](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/419/pourquoi-les-jurons-qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois-sont-ils-des-sacres)).