# Suggestions pour une amélioration de la qualité des votes

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Quelques remarques de modérateurs lues au fil de *Cosette* (1) me poussent à suggérer quelques améliorations techniquement simples à mettre en œuvre et qui pourraient permettre une meilleure perception de la somme des votes en tant que *valeur* résultante d'une contribution ainsi qu'une meilleure compréhension des motivations nécessaires au vote.

Mon opinion générale sur le problème étant que les votes ne permettent plus de distinguer la qualité des contributions parce que le vote a perdu un sens, une signification qu'il convient de lui redonner.

**A/ Dégradation significative de la *valeur* (Du nombre représentatif de la somme des votes) sur les "*réponses* *"locked by community"***

Je crois que quelle que soit la *valeur en soi* d'une contribution présumée honnête d'un présumé honnête contributeur, sa *valeur* ne peut en aucun cas apparaître inférieure ou égale à la *valeur* d'une contribution dégagée par *community* pour cause de spam / abuse...
C'est le cas par exemple [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39552/se-sentir-saisir-vs-se-sentir-saisi/39555#39555) :  (contribution de LPH / contribution de user19418)

Il doit être assez simple techniquement pour l'automate community de forcer la somme totale des votes de la contribution dégagée à une valeur très basse, voire, mais peut-être plus compliqué, de supprimer l'affichage de la somme des votes pour les contributions *locked*.

**B/ Possibilité accordée de revenir sur son vote.**

Passé un certain temps, il n'est pas possible de revenir sur un vote déjà commis à moins que la réponse ne soit à nouveau éditée.

Il est parfois des questions pas simples, voire dont la formulation peut laisser une ambiguïté sur l'angle sous lequel la réponse "doit" être abordée.
Ces questions attirent en général peu de réponses et, les réponses sont généralement compliquées.

Dans le contexte d'une lecture rapide, moyennant deux ou trois aprioris sur l'implicite, je peux voter, dans un sens ou dans l'autre une réponse selon mon jugement qu'elle répond où non à **ma** compréhension de la question + **mes** aprioris de l'instant.

Parce que, plus tard, le sujet me tarabuste un peu ou revient à la surface par le truchement de liens dans la marge droite, je vais revenir sur cette question et... possiblement comprendre tout autre chose (de la question ou de la réponse), considérer alors mon vote précédent inapproprié sauf que... je ne peux plus revenir dessus.

En bilan des courses, alors que je me crois quelque compétence sur le sujet, je m'abstiens de voter sur les réponses apportées à ces questions compliquées alors que c'est précisément sur ces questions-là que l'honnête lecteur aimerait connaître l'opinion des autres et que mon vote aurait le plus de sens.

**C/ : Changement des termes good / bad au profit de correct / not correct.**

Je sais que cette suggestion a déjà été faite [ici](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/729/community-should-cause-correc-ou-community-pris-en-flagrant-d%C3%A9lit-did%C3%A9alisme) et n'a manifestement pas reçu le soutien de la communauté, néanmoins qui sait si... avec le temps et les constats récents... donc... je retente le coup :

Si on invite le lecteur à voter suivant le jugement bon / mauvais, on invite absolument tout le monde à voter sur la base d'un simple jugement de goût qu'absolument tout le monde est autorisé à prononcer. On incite alors implicitement le lecteur à se prononcer sur la base d'un *J'aime / J'aime pas* popularisé par facebook. Le vote est devenu rien d'autre qu'un *like*.

Je crois qu'avec un ***correct / pas correct***, il est possible de limiter les votes sans valeur réelle indicative dans la mesure où on invite le lecteur à une lecture critique de la contribution et à se prononcer en fonction d'un jugement critique. Si le lecteur sait ne pas avoir de compétence pour juger de la correction sur un sujet donné, il s'abstiendra évidemment.

**D: Suppression de l'information d'acceptation par l'auteur de la question.**

Là, je réalise bien que cette question mériterait un fil particulier et que mon opinion peut être de nature à décourager quelques bonnes volontés et aussi qu'elle ne reflète probablement que mon expérience personnelle.

Je tiens pour littéralement absurde cette notion d'acceptation par l'auteur de la question (et les diverses (sur)valorisations qu'elle implique) et ce sur la base d'une simple évidence :

Quand je pose *honnêtement* une question *honnête*. Je veux dire par là, une question dont je ne connais pas la réponse, que je me retrouve avec plusieurs réponses différentes, eh bien je me trouve très logiquement **le plus mal placé** pour élire la meilleure... alors je fais quoi ? Bhein... je vais élire celle qui... me plaît le mieux! Mon vote n'a donc plus aucun sens.

**E/ Suppression des badges obtenus sur la base de nombres de votes**

Je tiens ces badges pour une incitation au vote absolument dénué de tout **sens**. Les "scores" exigés (300 et 600 si j'ai bonne mémoire) incitent à une véritable frénésie le collectionneur de Kudos. Je peux d'ailleurs noter (non sans surprise) la présence sur FSE de *contributeurs* qui, sans aucune maîtrise de la langue française ont tout de même pu voter plus de 400 fois sans offir plus de deux *"contributions*". Quel est le sens de ces votes ? Quel est le bien fondé du jugement qui y a conduit ?

---

<sup>1 : "...le fait que les votes ne permettent plus de distinguer le bon contenu du reste." by Stéphane in Cosette et autres relatifs.</sup>

<sup>NDaCOSwt : Pour être conséquent, je downvoterai de facto toute réponse qui n'irait pas dans mon sens à au moins 2O%, et accepterai en meilleure réponse celle qui m'accordera l'évidence sur le plus de points parmi les cinq mentionnés.</sup>

<sup>NDaCOSwt : La note précédente est une blague.</sup>

Comment: J'ai lu, je réfléchis avant de répondre. Toute réponse qu'elle soit ici ou ailleurs doit être longuement pesé . À priori je suis d'accord sur certains points seulement. Ce qui  à priori me laisse perplexe c'est « Il doit être assez simple techniquement pour l'automate community de forcer la somme totale ». FL est un petit bout d'un tout...  et techniquement je crains que ce soit difficile surtout quand le tout part en quenouille ([au cas où ça t'ai échappé](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/176183)).

Comment: @Laure : J'ai dit *assez simple techniquement* car je connais un peu le programme qui tourne ici. Il s'agit juste d'un point de vue technique, je m'imagine bien qu'obtenir l'accord de l'ensemble de la communauté serait une autre paire de manches.

Comment: @Laure Je tiendrai ta question sur le *dois-je plussoyer* (et à laquelle je ne répondrai évidemment pas) pour un plussoiement en soi dans la mesure où tu te poses effectivement la question du **sens** de ton vote.

Comment: À mon avis, vous accordez trop d'importance au concept. Il s'agit seulement de répondre à des questions mais pas de se former.

Comment: @Fólkvangr : Trop d'importance au concept ? Oui, nécessairement. Quand il est question de *perte de sens*, c'est bien au concept qu'il faut revenir. Pour ce qui est du but du jeu (*répondre / se former*) je ne cacherai jamais que j'ai appris beaucoup de choses en répondant à des questions. (Et rien du tout de l'information du décompte de votes)

Comment: *Si le lecteur sait ne pas avoir de compétence pour juger de la correction sur un sujet donné, il s'abstiendra évidemment.* Quel optimisme !

Comment: Point E : c'est vrai de tous les sites de SE, pas spécifique à FL.

Comment: Je viens de relire [ce que j'avais écrit il y a 5 ans](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/561/358) et, pas mal d'éléments pourraient être repris dans une éventuelle réponse à ta question.

Comment: Je ne peux pas m'empêcher de faire le lien avec [ceci](https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-49960387?intlink_from_url=https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology&link_location=live-reporting-story). Votes et crédibilité.